# Application not able to invoke rest call in Win 2016 server, but works fine in Win 10

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Web Application not able to invoke rest call in our newly deployed VPS server  which has a Windows 2016 server.  The code works fine in a Windows 10 server where it is able to invoke the rest call.  Is there some module missing in the 2016 Windows server (.Net version 4.7.2) this is not working ? The Web application and the back end rest services are deployed in the same VPS machine. The original web application code was compiled on .net version 4.5.

Webconfig has the following entries.  We tried configuring with the service IP address, domain name address and also as "localhost".

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
<!--     <add key="EmailServiceURL" value="https://services.mydomain:9876/EmailService" /> -->
<!--     <add key="EmailServiceURL" value="https://localhost:9876/EmailService" /> -->
     <add key="EmailServiceURL" value="https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9876/EmailService" /> 
  </appSettings>
```

The rest api is correctly getting invoked when a rest client calls it from the same VPS server.

It is a simple code that works in a Windows 10 env and not a new VPS Window 16 server we set up. Do you think any .NET installation components are missing ?

```
string UrlString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["M3QEmailServiceURL"];
        string strMethod = "POST";
<... more code ...>
         result = InvokeWebRequest(UrlString, strMethod, strJsonData.ToString());
<... more code ...>
        public string InvokeWebRequest(string UrlString, string strMethod, string jsonString)
        {
            var request = WebRequest.Create(UrlString);
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Method = strMethod;
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(jsonString);
            }
            var response = request.GetResponse();
            string strResult = string.Empty;

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                strResult = sr.ReadToEnd();
                sr.Close();
            }
            return strResult.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: what does "not able to invoke" mean?  do you get error messages? do you get an unexpected result from the server?  what does the code that you are using to make this call look like?  There isn't enough information in your question to really provide a concrete answer to your issue.

Comment: Added the code that calls the rest service. Seems the call is not going out to the rest server. No errors are seen in any logs. It may be calling the rest service but silently failing.   The REST service  server does not show in its log indicating a call came in.

Comment: "System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Exception exception)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)\r\n   at